# require_once() Causing categories and tag pages on dashboard to not refrsh

Tags: functions, categories, tags

I have a number of code blocks being included in my functions.php file that seam to be affecting my category and tags pages on the dashboard. Categories and Tags are being added but page does not refresh itself and has to be manually refreshed? any idea as to what might be causing this ?

**functions.php**

```
<?php

/* Translation File
********************************************/
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'magneton', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/languages' );

/* Includes
********************************************/
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/framework/inc/breadcrumbs.php' ); // load Breadcrumbs
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/framework/inc/banner-image.php' ); // get featured image url
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/framework/inc/title.php' ); // get the page title

/** 
 * THEME SETUP
 * @method magneton_theme_setup
 * - Adds theme support
 * - Registers navigation menus  
 */
function magneton_theme_setup() {      
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'image', 'video', 'quote' ) ); // post formats
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );// post thumbnails
    add_theme_support( 'html5' );// HTML5 
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );// automatic feed links 

    register_nav_menus( array(
        'topbar'    => __( 'Topbar', 'magneton' ),
        'main'      => __( 'Main', 'magneton' ),        
        'mobile'    => __( 'Mobile', 'magneton' ),
        'sidebar'   => __( 'Sidebar', 'magneton' ),
        'footer'    => __( 'Footer', 'magneton' )
    ) );
 }
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'magneton_theme_setup');

/** 
 * ENQUEUE STYLESHEETS
 * @method magneton_stylsheets
 * - Enqueue Boostrap
 * - Enqueue Font Awesome
 * - Enqueue Magneton style 
 */
 function magneton_stylsheets() {     
     wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, '3.3.7', 'all' );
     wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, '4.7.0', 'all' );     
     wp_enqueue_style( 'magneton', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap', 'font-awesome'), '1.0.0', 'all');
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'magneton_stylsheets' );

 /** 
 * ENQUEUE SCRIPTS
 * @method magneton_scripts
 * -  HoverIntent
 * -  Superfish
 * -  Magnav
 * -  Magneton scripts
 * -  Comment reply script
 */
 function magneton_scripts() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hoverintent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hoverIntent.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.9.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'hoverintent' ), '1.7.9', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magnav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magnav.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magneton', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magneton.js', array( 'jquery', 'hoverintent', 'superfish', 'magnav' ), '1.0.0', true );

    // Conditionals scripts
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'magneton_scripts' );
```

Comment: Why do you think the above shared code is affecting your category and tags pages on the dashboard? Do you mean if you remove that code it works fine?

Comment: I tried removing one thing after another to see what was causing the problem. So through a process of eliminations i figure out it was the section of `include_once()`. It did not seam to make any difference which once of the includes only there was and include. I posted the entire code in case it could be useful in debugging.

Comment: It seems it is not require_once which is causing this issue but the code in the files that require_once loads is causing it.  You can inspect the code of these files for the issue or enable WP debug on your site to check whether it generates any error.

Comment: @VinodDalvi, thank that helps i have the debug set to true but i am not getting any error or notices winch is strange.